# Remove elements from a List according to specific criterias or values present in adjacent lists

Tags: java, java-8

I have a problem that I'm trying to wrap my head around concerning List and editing of said list.

I have a list of objects representing contracts. One of the properties of said contract is another list of objects representing suspensions, which have a motive, a beginning date, and an ending date.

My goal is to check if, accross all contracts, some suspensions have the same specific motive and the same beginning, and if so, I need to check which of those suspension has the longest suspension period.

Once I've done that, I need to remove in each contract the shorter suspension objects from their respective list of suspensions.

And then, do it again in case other suspensions accross all contracts have the same beginning date, but different from the one already handled.

I just can't seem to fathom how to code this properly with a decent algorithm and avoiding looping over several times around the same thing. If you guys have any suggestion, it'd be greatly appreciated.

So far, this is all I've got (ie : retrieving contracts with the right motive)

```
            List<Contracts> contractListWithCorrectMotive= contractList.stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getSuspensions().stream().anyMatch(isSuspensionWithMotive("603")))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            if (contractListWithCorrectMotive.size() > 1) {
/// Do the magic trick

            }
```

After a bit of thinking, I came up with the following solution. One of my problems is that I cannot test this easily as I lack the correct files needed to start the batch in this specific case (this is an application developped using spring batch).

```
            // Initialize an arraylist of already handled suspensions
            ArrayList<Suspension> alreadyHandledSuspensions = new ArrayList<>();

            // Check if I got more than one suspension objet with the right motive
            if (suspensionListWithCorrectMotive.size() > 1) {

                Iterator<Suspension> itr = suspensionListWithCorrectMotive.iterator();

                // Iterate over it
                while (itr.hasNext()) {

                    // Assign values for Suspension and start Date
                    Suspension suspensionWithCorrectMotive = itr.next();
                    if (alreadyHandledSuspensions.contains(suspensionWithCorrectMotive)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    LocalDate suspensionStartDate = suspensionWithCorrectMotive.getStartDate();

                    // Retrieve Suspensions with same start Date in the list
                    List<Suspension> listSuspensionWithSameStartDate = listeBlocsSuspensionDetentionProvisoire.stream()
                            .filter(isSuspensionWithSameStartDate(suspensionStartDate)).collect(Collectors.toList());

                    // if at least 2
                    if (listSuspensionWithSameStartDate.size() > 1) {

                        // Retrieve the object with the maximum value for the ending date
                        Optional<Suspension> optSuspensionWithMaxEndDate = listSuspensionWithSameStartDate.stream().max(
                                Comparator.comparing(b -> getEndDate(b, otherNecessaryParameterToSetDefaultValue)));

                        // Remove this object from the list so that only the shorter ones are present
                        if (optSuspensionWithMaxEndDate.isPresent()) {
                            listSuspensionWithSameStartDate.remove(optSuspensionWithMaxEndDate.get());
                        }

                        // Iterate over the contract to retrieve the list of suspensions, then remove
                        // the suspension if they are part of the List previously created
                        for (Contract contract : contractListWithCorrectSuspensionMotive) {
                            contract.getSuspension().removeIf(s -> listSuspensionWithSameStartDate.contains(s));
                        }

                        // And here, I think this won't work: remove from the list I'm currently
                        // iterating over the suspensions that I just "deleted"
                        // suspensionListWithCorrectMotive.removeAll(listSuspensionWithSameStartDate);

                        // Add the list of suspension with same start date as the iteration (including
                        // the iteration itself) to the list of already handled suspensions
                        alreadyHandledSuspensions.addAll(listSuspensionWithSameStartDate);

                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Is iterating over the list multiple times _actually_ a problem?

Comment: Hey Andy. It's not so much a problem I guess. But I just wanted a clean way to do it. I'm posting an edit to show what I came up with.